# Travel entire streets segments

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, arcgis-10.4, fields-attributes, vbscript

I m using ArcGIS 10.4.1 and Network Analyst extension, in the network dataset properties-> Attributes. I created an attribute called PromoteStops1, next in Script Evaluators, I used the following script to force VRP solver to travel entire streets segments. (The basic idea is that if a street has deliveries you it better not to leave that street until there are no more deliveries). The deliveries have service time so this script works as follows;

```
restricted = False
a = Turn.Angle
If a >= 45 Then
    If fromEdge.AttributeValueByName("ServiceTim")= 0.5 And toEdge.AttributeValueByName("ServiceTim") = 0.5 Then
        restricted = True
    End If
End If
```

[image]

[image]

(ServiceTim is the field name in road's shapefile attributes table).

When I try to solve the VRP I get the following message;

Error: The evaluator failed to return a value. [Attribute: PromoteStops1,

Source: FT_Attica_Roads_Final_Clip1_Spa, OID = 4002, EID = 3406]

Error: Network element evaluator error. [Script Control Error -2147352319]

[image]

Is there anything wrong with the variable names?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to make your code legible by using code formatting (`{}`) and placing the error message in the question body as text (which makes it legible on all devices and searchable by future users). Please take the [Tour].

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible sources of errors:

- Edges do not have turn angle, turns do.

So, `a=Turn.Angle` will receive invalid values, if so.

- Any value used in the pre-logic script code must be passed as a parameter.